# How to determine algorithm complexity / order of growth with division?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

I am trying to understand order of growth for a function with different exponents and division.

I have an exercise for which

*F(n) = an<sup>3</sup>/ (kn<sup>2</sup> - cn)*

The answer specify growth order in **THETA** notation of n<sup>3</sup>

Why it is not n<sup>3</sup> / n<sup>2</sup> = n<sup>3-2</sup> = n?

I am thinking it should due to exponent subtracting...?

Would it be different if asked for **Big Omicron** or **Big Omega**?

Answer (score 0):

If `k, c, a > 0` and they are constant, the answer is not true. It is `Theta(n)`, as the limit of `F(n)/n` when `n` goes to infinity, it would be `a/k` and as it is constant and greater than zero, we can say `F(n) = Theta(n)`. Also, base on the definition of these asymptotic notations, `F(n)` is `Omega(n)` and `O(n)` too.

Comment: Thanks, yes for positive coefficients. So would the answer be n (following n3^/n^2 simplification) ?